# Apache .htaccess RewriteCond on Directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

I have the following directory structure in htdocs:

```
htdocs/
  .htaccess
  index.php
  foo/
  bar/
  priv/
```

I'm trying to achieve clean URLs and basically want everything routed through `index.php`. My `.htaccess` file is as follows:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # <- referring to this next
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

This works well in the sense that I can access legitimate files inside of `foo/` and `bar/` directly, however I'm also able to access files in `priv/` which is what I want to disallow. How do I modify the above referenced line to basically say: "disable for files that are NOT in `priv/`"?

---

EDIT: I'm trying to avoid having to do "`priv/.htaccess`" -> "`deny from all`", and instead would like to process this in `index.php` like any other "pretty url" conversion.

Comment: hi, i would add an additional .htaccess in priv denying all access.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add another `RewriteCond` with the condition just to match `^priv/` and combine it with OR:

```
RewriteCond $0 ^priv/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Now this rule is applied if either the matched partial path starts with `priv/` *or* if the request cannot be mapped onto an existing file.

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect. I really wish the Apache documentation was easier to find stuff in.

Comment: @Gumbo, If you don't mind me starting up such an old tread again, would you care to elaborate a little on the "$0" for the first RewriteCond. Shouldn't "$" be used with RewriteRule only?

Comment: @Matte The `$0` refers to the matched string of the whole pattern of the corresponding `RewriteRule`.